# Changing a div's id on click

Tags: javascript, css

How do I add an onClick listener to a div.
I want to change the name of a div to divclass active if it was inactive previously & then remove the word 'active' if user click on the list again.
I'm at a loss how to do this. 
This is what I've tried so far

```
<script>

$function tog(){
$(this).toggleClass('active');
return false;
}



$(function() {

var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

$(document).click(function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-4').removeClass('active');
});

});
</script>
```

where the div whose class name I want to change is defined as below

```
<div id="dd" onclick="tog()" class="wrapper-dropdown-4">
  <!--something-->
  </div>
```

I've tried this..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$('#dd').on('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('active')
});
</script>

<style>
.active {
color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-4">
ddddd
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this now?

I'm inspecting the element id via chrome developer's tool & I don't see any change using this code. So, can anyone please help?
Thanks. :)

Comment: the dom should be loaded before you write you function , thats why we use $(function(){});

Answer (score 2):

The only script you need is

```
$(function(){
    $('#dd').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7vH5k/)

Comment: Yes.. I think that should work, but it didn't work. Is there any problem with my code (I've added that part in my question )

Comment: @user1984849 You need to use `document.ready`. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the object $(this) is not recognizable , use tog(this)

```
  <script>
     function tog(obj)
     {
        $(obj).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
     }



 $(function() {

 var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

 $(document).click(function() {
 // all dropdowns
 $('.wrapper-dropdown-4').removeClass('active');
 });

 });
 </script>

 <div id="dd" onclick="tog(this)" class="wrapper-dropdown-4">
   <!--something-->
 </div>
```

not the best way to do it, you can bind the event ,by registering the click in the event.

Comment: No.  If you are using jQuery, use it to bind events instead of using inline event handlers.